# Haskell: Basic Reading Int

Tags: haskell, io

The objective is to code the game of Nim in Haskell as a school assignment. I'm new to Haskell and get weird behavior when I try to read input.

The goal is to read two integers. Instead of printing the first message, then prompting and then going on to the second one, it just prints the two messages and I'm unable to give proper input. What is wrong here?

```
type Board = [Int]      -- The board
type Heap  = Int        -- id of heap
type Turn  = (Int, Int) -- heap and number of stars to remove

readInt :: String -> IO Int
readInt msg = do putStr (msg ++ "> ")
                 inp <- getChar
                 let x = ord inp
                 return x

readTurn :: Board -> IO(Turn)
readTurn b = do heap <- readInt "Select heap:"
                amt <- readInt "Select stars:"
                print heap
                print amt
                return(heap, amt)
```

Comment: Why do you use `getChar`? It's obvious that this isn't very good for reading integers, isn't it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it's not that obvious. In some situations one might want to treat each character as a separate integer (based on ASCII or whatever) as has been written here; it's a little, err, unconventional, and not what the poster wants, but it's *not* obviously wrong. After all, `getChar >>= return . ord` has the expected type: `IO Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `stdout` is line-buffered by default, which means that nothing gets output until you print a newline. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use `hFlush stdout` after printing the prompt to flush the buffer.
2. Use `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` at the start of your program to disable output buffering.

Also, using `getChar` and `ord` will read a single character and give you its ASCII value, which is probably not what you wanted. To read and parse a number, use `readLn`:

```
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

readInt :: String -> IO Int
readInt msg = do
    putStr (msg ++ "> ")
    hFlush stdout
    readLn
```

Comment: @user1329182, if hammar's answer solved your question, please indicate so by accepting the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`readChar` reads only one character at a time. I assume you want instead to read a whole line, convert it to a number (possibly with more than one digit), and continue. You need to use `getLine :: IO String` and `read :: Read a => String -> a`:

```
readInt :: String -> IO Int
readInt msg = do
    putStr (msg ++ "> ")
    hFlush stdout
    inp <- getLine
    return (read inp)
```

Comment: @leftaroundabout: sure, but I wanted to give him a minimum set of changes from his solution, it's his homework after all :)

Comment: As it does not hFlush stdout this print the text after reading the values in some cases